# How to fix seg fault core dumped error for ifstream

Tags: c++, matrix, segmentation-fault

**input file**

```
9
2 8
0 6
8 5
2 4
3 1
2 3
4 1
6 1
2 6
7 5
1 7
```

**Code**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
   ifstream in;

   char infile[40];
   int c, u, v;

   cout << "Please enter the input data file name(NO SPACES): ";
   cin >> infile;

   in.open(infile);
   while(in.fail()) {
      cout << "Please enter a CORRECT input data file name(NO SPACES): ";
      cin >> infile;
      in.open(infile);
   }


   //adj matrix
   c = in.get();
   int array[c-1][c-1];
   for(int i=0; i<c; i++) {
      for(int j=0; j<c; j++) {
         array[i][j] = 0;
      }
   }

   while(!in.eof()) {
      u = in.get();
      v = in.get();
      array[u][v] = 1;
   }

   cout << c << endl;
   for(int i=0;i<c;i++) {
      cout << i << "   ";
      for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
         cout << array[i][j] << " ";
      }
      cout << endl;
   }

   in.close();

   return 0;
}
```

**What the output should look like**

```
9
0   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
2   0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
3   0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4   0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
6   0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
7   0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
8   0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

When prompted for the file name, if I enter an incorrect file name it will continue to prompt me for a CORRECT input file, but when a CORRECT file name is entered I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

I want an adjacency matrix for the corresponding edges given in the input file to be outputted.

Comment: Two things: use a `std::string` instead of an array of `char`s, and the character `'9'` is not the same as the integer `9`, read the integers from your file with something like `int foo; in >> foo;`.

Comment: A third thing: a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) simplifies everything. You can probably pare away a lot of this code and still get the same error. (And it's probably just undefined behavior from confusing `'9'` with `9` and using it as an index.)

Comment: `int array[c-1][c-1];` is not valid C++ code. How did you get your code to compile?

Comment: @RSahu I have no clue how it compiled. I'm a novice coder and still figuring everything out so I wish I could tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::basic_istream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) will extract one character at a time . So `'9'` is not same as `9`

Do like following *<sub>assuming your file entities are correct and in known format</sub>* :

```
   in >> c;
   int array[c][c]; // Indices from 0 to c-1
   for(int i=0; i<c; i++) {
      for(int j=0; j<c; j++) {
         array[i][j] = 0;
      }
   }

   while( in >> u >> v) {
      array[u][v] = 1;
   }
```

---

Also use `std::string` for file name instead of char array. Then you can use

```
in.open( infile.c_str() ); // Pre C++11
```

or directly

```
in.open(infile); // with C++11
```

Comment: True and correct, but the segfault is presumably caused by the array definition `int array[c-1][c-1];` Should be `int array[c+1][c+1];`

Comment: @user1781290 it should be `int array[c][c];` only since OP input has 0 and 8 as min max.